# How can i fix system.web.dll version conflict?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, conflict, razorengine

I use RazorEngine V 3.0.8 in my project(Asp.net MVC 4) for parsing email template. I use system.web.dll version 1.0.0 in my project.
Every thing is ok on my pc as local site and It works. but on server this error was shown:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

but I didn't use 'System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0 on my project.
also when I add 'System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0 to my project , I have problem for parsing email template with RazorEngine and this error was shown:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name:
>   'System.Web.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'    at
>   RazorEngine.Compilation.DefaultCompilerServiceFactory.CreateCompilerService(Language
>   language)    at
>   RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplateType(String
>   razorTemplate, Type modelType)    at
>   RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplate[T](String
>   razorTemplate, T model)    at
>   RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.Parse[T](String razorTemplate,
>   T model)    at RazorEngine.Razor.Parse[T](String razorTemplate, T
>   model)    at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)    at
>   Service.Implementation.EmailService.InitializeTemplate(String
>   templateBody, Object model) in
>   c:\Badr\Service\Implementation\EmailService.cs:line
>   21    at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)    at
>   Service.Implementation.EmailService.SendSingleEmail(String from,
>   String name, String[] to, String subject, String templateBody, Object
>   model, EmailSendMethod sendMethod) in
>   c:\Badr\Service\Implementation\EmailService.cs:line
>   32    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , EmailService , String ,
>   String , String[] , String , String , Object , EmailSendMethod )    at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute8[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6,
>   T7 arg7)    at
>   Service.Implementation.EmailService.SendSingleEmail(String from,
>   String name, String to, String subject, String templateBody, Object
>   model, EmailSendMethod sendMethod) in
>   c:\Badr\Service\Implementation\EmailService.cs:line
>   27    at
>   Service.Implementation.UserEmailService.SendLicenseToUser(Guid token)
>   in
>   c:\Badr\Service\Implementation\UserEmailService.cs:line
>   86    at
>   Web.Controllers.PurchaseController.CreatePurchaseAndSendEmail(IEnumerable`1
>   cartItems) in
>   c:\Badr\Web\Controllers\PurchaseController.cs:line
>   759
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Please help me what should I do?

Comment: can you please post a stack trace? This can help to resolve the issue

Comment: The required information has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into your stack trace and looks like it trying to load
System.Web.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0 
not System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0
so please try to check references in Web.config files you can also try to deploy your site with System.Web.Razor.dll (select always copy) maybe this help